# Path beween tree nodes, cost between edges differs in direction of traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, jgrapht

I have a shortest-path problem and not sure what the right approach would be.

Given a tree, I would like to find the path and the path cost between two nodes, where the cost differs depending on the direction of traversal.

For example if A is a child node of B, A->B could have a cost of 3 and B->A has a cost of 4.

Is there a Java library where I can model this problem by setting up a graph with nodes and path costs in different directions as defined above, and have a way to get the path and path cost between two nodes?

Comment: There is exactly one simple path between any two nodes in a tree. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, each path in a tree between nodes is a unique simple path, it simplifies the problem. However, I would prefer a tested library with the ability to define the path costs as above versus coding from scratch.

Comment: Should be quite simple to implement. Just take the Dijkstra and have a different cost in each direction. Or you could use any implementation that allows directed graphs and then just make a separate path for each direction.

Comment: Just because I want to make sure that you're not confusing everyone here, do you actually mean graph or do you really mean tree? You tagged the question as graph but you say tree. It really changes the problem depending on the two.

Comment: The nodes are connected in a tree structure (root node, unique simple path between nodes.). However, because of this path cost use case above I thought graph might be a good tag, (since a tree is a special case of a graph anyway). Useful comments, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a single path between each pair of nodes in a tree. Thus it doesn't really matter if prizes differ in the two directions - find the single path and then compute its prize in the two directions. Note that what you have is not a shortest path problem - you have a **single path**.